# how to modify the selinux labels of a file

Tags: rhel, selinux

In RHEL 8.9,

in `/etc/systemd/system/` I created a `custom.service` file, using `vi` as root.  In doing so it has these labels by default as shown by `ls -ldZ`

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root unconfined_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0 1086 Mar  5 14:41  custom.service
```

The rest of the files in this location have the following as their labels.
How do I modify my `custom.service` file to have only these specific labels?

```
system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `chcon` to modify SELinux Security Context for files. Please refer [man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon) pages for more info.

```
sudo chcon system_u:object_r:systemd_unit_file_t:s0 custom.service
```

This should change the security context to your needs.